# Angular - Module not found

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have tried to create an angular application using ui-router.

In HTML file I have this in the body element:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="ang">
    <header ng-include="'templates/head.html'"></header>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <footer ng-include="'templates/foot.html'"></footer>
</div>

<script src="Dependencies/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="Dependencies/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/ang.js"></script>
```

In the module, I have this:

```
angular.module('ang', ['ui-router'])
```

But Chrome gives me out this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7
angular.js:80 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ang due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ang' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ang
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:80:12)
    at file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:1797:17
    at ensure (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:1721:38)
    at module (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:1795:14)
    at file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:4064:22
    at forEach (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:335:20)
    at loadModules (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:4048:5)
    at createInjector (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:3974:11)
    at doBootstrap (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:1484:20)
    at bootstrap (file:///home/user/Desktop/ang/Dependencies/angular.js:1505:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ang&p1=Error%3A%20%…F%2F%2Fhome%2Fuser%2FDesktop%2Fang%2FDependencies%2Fangular.js%3A1505%3A12)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using `ng-app="ang"` define module as

```
angular.module('ang', ['ui-router'])
```

instead of

```
angular.module('app', ['ui-router'])
```

Change the sequence of these files as `angular.js` should be loaded before `angular-ui-router.min.js`

```
<script src="Dependencies/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still doesn't help, it gives the same error, just with another name

Comment: @John, Change the sequence of the file, load `angular.js` before `angular-ui-router.min.j`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answers were very useful and probably saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `angular-ui-router.min.js` file after the `angular.js` file,

```
<script src="Dependencies/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

**And** define the dependency like `ui.router` not the `ui-router`.

```
angular.module('ang', ['ui.router']);
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iZkLXpssU18X1QXJT8FH?p=preview)

Comment: I spent 4 hours to discover my problem was the "ui.router" and not "ui-router". +1

Answer (score 3):

Your angular script reference should appear before angular-ui-router script reference.

`<script src="Dependencies/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="Dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>`